# Como usar o hover em uma classe para alterar outra classe?

Tags: css, css-hover

gente seguinte, eu tenho uma classe e outra classe embaixo dela... porém a classe de baixo precisa ficar invisivel ate o usuario passar o mouse na classe de cima, então eu coloquei nela opacity:0 , e tentei colocar um hover na classe de cima para quando o usuario passasse o mouse nela a classe de baixo passaria a ficar com opacity:1, mas não ta funcionando, é possivel fazer isso ou estou fazendo errado? aqui vão as classes, estou usando o background so para testes no navegador.

```
.foto-funcionario{
background: blue;
height: 400px;
```

}

```
.contato-funcionario{
height: 75px;
background: green;
opacity: 0;
```

}

```
.foto-funcionario:hover .contato-funcionario{
opacity: 1;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Como a opacidade do elemento pai (`.foto-funcionario`) é `0`, todos os elementos filhos não serão exibidos até que ele seja visível.

É como se você estivesse tentando dar opacidade para um elemento que "veste" um outro com opacidade 0. Como uma capa de invisibilidade.

Para o elemento filho aparecer, o pai tem que ter `opacity: 1;` também. É assim que funciona a cascata.

Para isso você também teria que adicionar `.foto-funcionario:hover {opacity:1;}` no seu código.

Não sei exatamente o efeito que você deseja alcançar, mas talvez seja uma boa brincar com `rgba()` e/ou `transparent` nos `background` de cada elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Em teoria o que você está fazendo está correto. Algumas probabilidades de erro que estou vendo ocorreriam apenas se você não definir uma `width` para suas divs (o que eu não vejo no seu CSS) seu HTML estiver correto de alguma forma. Está assim?

```
<div class="foto-funcionario">
    <div class="contato-funcionario">
    </div>
</div>
```

Tente definir uma `width` para as suas classes se seu HTML estiver correto.